Cross product of a rotation matrix
My understanding is that for rotation matrix
$$Ra \times   Rb = R(a\times b)$$.
I have seen a proof involving determinants but is there a cleaner way?

Since THE right way to define the cross product is via determinant or exterior product, I don’t think you can make the proof cleaner without using determinant or something similar.

$
\def\L{\lambda}
\def\T{\times}
$Use these well known rules from vector analysis
$$\eqalign{
(a\T b)\T c &= (c^Ta)b - (c^Tb)a \\
c\T c &= 0 \\
}$$
to calculate the triple cross product of three rotated vectors
$$\eqalign{
(Ra\T Rb)\T Rc
 &= (c^TR^TRa)Rb - (c^TR^TRb)Ra \\
 &= (c^Ta)Rb - (c^Tb)Ra \\
 &= R\,\Big[(c^Ta)b - (c^Tb)a\Big] \\
 &= R\,\Big[(a\T b)\T c\Big] \\
}$$
Substituting $c=(a\T b)$ yields
$$\eqalign{
(Ra\T Rb)\T R(a\T b)
 &= R\,\Big[(a\T b)\T(a\T b)\Big] \;\equiv\; 0 \\
}$$
This means that the initial vectors are parallel, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
(Ra\T Rb) = \L\,R(a\T b) \\
}$$
If you calculate the norm of both sides you will discover that $\L=1$
